# <input type="file"> - custom styles/css

Tags: html, css, file-io

Is there a way to make `<input type="file">` look the same in all browsers using some CSS ?

Comment: Dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=style+input+file

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style "input file" with CSS3 / Javascript ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226167/how-to-style-input-file-with-css3-javascript)

Comment: nice question... but i have tried everything, doesn't work... hope someone has the answer!

Comment: Why is it necessary to answer a question that has dozens and dozens of well-answered duplicates?

Answer (score 4):

Quirksmode.org has an interesting article about it: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Answer (score 2):

try this -

1. Take a normal  and put it in an element with
   position: relative.
2. To this same parent element, add a
   normal  and an image, which
   have the correct styles. Position
   these elements absolutely, so that
   they occupy the same place as the
   .
3. Set the z-index of the  to 2 so that it lies on
   top of the styled input/image.
4. Finally, set the opacity of the
    to 0. The  now becomes effectively
   invisible, and the styles
   input/image shines through, but you
   can still click on the "Browse"
   button. If the button is positioned
   on top of the image, the user
   appears to click on the image and
   gets the normal file selection
   window. (Note that you can't use
   visibility: hidden, because a truly
   invisible element is unclickable,
   too, and we need the  to remain clickable)
   Until here the effect can be
   achieved through pure CSS. However,
   one feature is still lacking.
5. When the user has selected a file,
   the visible, fake input field should
   show the correct path to this file,
   as a normal 
   would. It's simply a matter of
   copying the new value of the  to the fake input
   field, but we need JavaScript to do
   this.

More details - http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Answer (score 1):

You could try using swfupload, an open source project that embeds a tiny Flash file on the page instead of the file input... You can use CSS to style the button that triggers the flash upload however you want.

Downside: it can be tricky to work with, and of course then your users have to have flash.

Upside: multiple files are selectable at once in the upload dialog!

Answer (score 1):

you can simply style your own file input button.
just set the CSS attribute of your input element to `style="display:none"` and handle a click event in javascript. further reading:
[Using hidden file input elements using the click() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Using_hidden_file_input_elements_using_the_click()_method)

EDIT: turns out that this doesn't work anymore for security reasons. a little hack is to just set the css style to `visibility:hidden`.
Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philx_x/cgojh6t1/30/) where i place my `<input>` field somewhere at the end of my page and trigger the openFileDialog with an `<a>` element.

```
//html
<input id="openFileDialog" type="file" id="files" name="files[]" accept=".json, .txt" />

//js
$("#openFile").on("click", function () {
    //throws an error if browser doesn't support file upload
    checkFileApiCompatibility();

    //opens File Dialog
    $("#openFileDialog").click();
    $("#openFileDialog").on('change', function(){
        openFile(this);
    });
});
```