# How to style a html submit form?

Tags: html, css

Here is my file upload form

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="filetoupload" id="filetoupload" onchange="this.form.submit();">
</form>
```

It makes a 'choose file' button to select a file to upload, but how do style this button in css, as in change the colour, size, position and font?

I have tried `input[type=submit] {}` but that doesn't seem to work

Also, how can I change the words on the button from 'choose file' to 'Upload' ?

Answer (score 2):

The type is `file`, not `submit`, as indicated by `type="file"`:

```
input[type=file] {
    /* styles here */
}
```

Styling the button, however, is complex. As explained in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21842275/2057919), you have to shift the actual input field out of view, then add a button with your own styling.

Comment: Oh sorry that was a silly mistake :) But I have changed the css to type=file instead, but it only edits the space around the button, not the actual button, for example the color applies around the button but not to it

Comment: See my edit. Unfortunately, what you want to do is very tricky and requires a combination of CSS and JavaScript to get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You missed `file`, you are creating style for `submit`, as you have `input type="file"`:

```
input[type=file] {
    /* styles here */
}
```

And for second one, to change the words on the button from 'choose file' to 'Upload', add an attribute `value="Upload"`

```
<input type="file" name="filetoupload" id="filetoupload" value="Upload" onchange="this.form.submit();">
```

Comment: Thanks but I have changed that and it still says Choose file. The new code is <input type="file" name="filetoupload" id="filetoupload" value="Upload" onchange="this.form.submit();">

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky to do.  If you can use jQuery, try this code I threw together.

```js
$('input[type="file"]').change(function() {

  var value = $(this).val();

  var value = value.replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "")

  if (value) {
    $(this).siblings('#fileName').html(value);
  } else {

    $(this).siblings('#fileName').html('upload');

  }

});
```

```css
input[type=file] {
  display: none;
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
label > span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  transition: background 0.5s, color 0.5s;
}
label > span:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label>
    <input type="file" name="filetoupload" id="filetoupload" onchange="this.form.submit();"><span id="fileName">upload</span>
  </label>
</form>
```