# How can I get a file upload button's text?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm writing documentation for a web platform and I want to refer to a file upload button in my instructions. However, the exact text on the button depends on the browser. For example, Firefox calls it `Browse...` and Chrome calls it `Choose File`.

```
<input type="file">
```

Is it possible to access (not change) that text programmatically? I know I can detect the browser and set the text in the documentation accordingly, or even use a workaround to set the button text, but that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "access"?

Comment: He wants to pull the actual text into his documentation, I guess, based on what is the actual text on the button, based on whatever browser the user uses, but without having to resort to fetching the browser-info.

Comment: Unfortunately somebody deleted their answer so I will point to an answer from another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21842275/34806

Comment: @fenceop Are you trying to retrieve the value using client-side `javascript`?

Comment: please don't do what you're trying to do.  just list the different browsers and what each button is.  It'll make it a lot easier for someone who might have printed out the documentation and is referring to it on a different browser later, or the like.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty How is linked Question related to present Question? The `<label>` element does not change the `.value` of the `<input>` element within `ShadowDOM` of `<input type="file">` element.

Comment: But if you insist...  is your documentation meant to be read on the web?  If so, just insert the actual HTML element `<input type="file">` and then it'll appear how that browser wants it to appear.  (with maybe an `onclick="return false"`)

Comment: @guest271314 it gives the OP a way to make the button text consistent across all browsers, eliminating the need for retreiving the button text from each individual browser.

Comment: @APAD1 That is not what OP is asking. The Question specifically asks: _"Is it possible to access (not change) that text?"_

Comment: It solves the OP's problem but apparently we can't have any of that

Comment: I think guest271314 is confusing "change" with "set" as in a setter of a property.  If you can change the text so it is the same across browsers, I agree with paolobasso's approach.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Not confusing anything. The Question is clear. The expected result is not. It is not possible to "access" the `.value` of the `<input>` element in `<input type="file">` element using client-side `javascript` alone. Perhaps suggest edit of Question is you believe the inquiry is other than the actual text of current Question.

Comment: @fenceop The edit does not change the Question.

Comment: @guest271314 thanks, but since it has already been established that it is NOT POSSIBLE to do what they are asking, I think giving other suggestions is perfectly fine.

Comment: @APAD1 Suggestions to do what? The Question is specifically: _"Is it possible to access (not change) that text programmatically?"_ The Answer is No. Though chrome, chromium do allow inspection of `ShadowDOM`. Do not currently have access to nightly; firefox default `Developer Tools` settings does not appear to have `ShadowDOM` inspection enabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

This text is set by how the browser renders that specific HTML element.  There's no way to access or change that text.  It will never be loaded into the DOM, so finding via jQuery is also not an option.

For your documentation, you may want to address what the IE version of the text will be, then list Chrome, Safari, Firefox, etc.  It's the best way I can think of to explain to the user.

**EDIT**

Just thought I'd update and mention Shadow DOM because it's interesting and new to me.  You can enable this in Chrome Dev Tools -> settings -> Show user agent shadow DOM.  There you can actually view the rendered control and the text set to it.  Although, it's not accessible programmatically through client side scripting. :(

Comment: _"There's no way to access or change that text."_ It is possible to view the `ShadowDOM` of the element  which contains `<input>` element where `.value` is the rendered text at chrome, chromium.

Comment: I don't have experience with this.  But wouldn't it only be useful if the user is using Chrome, then?

Comment: Have not yet found a way to view the `ShadowDOM` of `<input type="file">` element at firefox. Will try nightly. It is not possible to "access (not change) that text programmatically".

Comment: How is the edited Answer different from this Answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40293559/ ?

Comment: It mentions ShadowDOM.

Comment: The original Answer at http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40293559/1 and current Answer both describe the `<input>` element within `ShadowDOM` of `<input type="file">` element being the source of the displayed text.

Comment: Oh, by original answer, you mean yours.  The context in which you used "original answer" made it seem like you were referring to my answer before the revision.  Yes, same as your answer, just wanted to add it to make sure everyone sees it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a label for the input_id and hide the input.

Example:

```css
label {
/*Just to simulate a button, you will put your button style*/
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: initial;
}

input {
/*hide the inout*/
  width: 0px;
  outline:none;
  opacity:0;
  visibility:none;
  height:0px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<label for="b1">
    Name
    <input type="file" id="b1">
</label>
```

Working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/dkypnhud/1/).

Comment: Ciao Paolo, I want to get the default text, not change it.

Comment: @fenceop It is not possible to "get the default text" of the `.value` of the  `<input>` element within `<input type="file">` `ShadowDOM` which renders the text.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to access (not change) that text programmatically?

<strike>No. It is not possible to access the `.value` of the `<input>` element within `<input type="file">` `ShadowDOM` which renders the text programmatically. The `.shadowRoot` property of `<input type="file">` `DOM` element where the `ShadowDOM` is displayed is set to `null`.</strike>

Chrome, chromium exposes the `.value` of `<input type="button" value="Choose File" pseudo="-webkit-file-upload-button">` at `ShadowDOM` of `<input type="file">` element at `.computedName` property of `input type="file"` element

```js
const UPLOAD_BUTTON_TEXT = document.querySelector("input[type=file]")
.computedName;
console.log(UPLOAD_BUTTON_TEXT);
```

```html
<input type="file" />
```

---

At chrome, chromium you can view the element

```
<input type="button" value="Choose File" pseudo="-webkit-file-upload-button">
```

which renders the text at `host` `<input type="file">` element by opening `DevTools`, selecting `Settings`, checking `Show user agent shadow DOM`, then inspecting the `<input type="file">` element.

```html
<input type="file">
```

Comment: So it doesn't really solve his problem of being able to access it programmatically.  Although, it's the most interesting thing I've learned about dev tools in a LONG time.

Comment: @CrazyPaste The "problem" cannot currently be solved. The `.value` cannot be accessed programmatically using client-side `javascript`