# How to call function that is parameter to Function.prototype.bind with value passed as parameter to Function.prototype.bind

Tags: javascript

Given situation

```
const n = 1;

function value(data) {
  return data === 1 && data;
}

function compare(data, next) {
  return !!(1 == data === next ? next(data) : value(data));
}

function isOne(a, b) {
  return !isNaN(a) && b()
}

function result(x, fn) {
  return fn ? fn(x) : x(n);
}
```

We can call `result()`

```
result(1, function(data) {return compare(data)}); // true

result(1, function(data) {return compare(value(data))}); // true

result(0, compare.bind(value)); // false

result(compare); // true

result(0, compare); // false


result(1, function(data) {
  return isOne(data, compare.bind(null, data, value))
}); // true
```

With each call pattern  resulting in return value of `result` being `true`.

How can we call `value` function as parameter to `compare` using `Function.prototype.bind`, `Function.prototype.call`, `Function.prototype.apply` or other approach without explicitly using `function() {}` pattern or changing the functions `value`, `compare` or `result`?

For example:

```
// where `value` is called with passed `1` as parameter which
// becomes parameter to `compare` call, which becomes parameter
// to `isOne`, with expected return value of `result` being `true`
result(1, isOne.bind(null, compare.bind(null, value)));
```

---

```js
const n = 1;

function value(data) {
  console.log("value", data);
  return data === 1 && data;
}

function compare(data, next) {
  console.log("compare", data, next);
  return !!(1 == data === next ? next(data) : value(data));
}

function result(x, fn) {
  console.log("result", x, fn);
  return fn ? fn(x) : x(n);
}

function isOne(a, b) {
  console.log("isOne", a, b);
  return !isNaN(a) && b()
}

console.log(result(1, function(data) {
  return compare(data, value)
})); // true
console.log(result(0, compare.bind(value))); // false
console.log(result(compare.bind(value))); // true
console.log(result(compare)); // true
console.log(result(1, function(data) {
  return isOne(data, compare.bind(null, data, value))
})); // true
 // how can we pass `1` to `value`
 // expected result: `true`, returns `false`
console.log(result(1, isOne.bind(null, compare.bind(null, value))));
```

Comment: You have some very unusual higher-order functions, and it is making your question hard to understand. Could you please create a simpler, more minimal example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Note, `isOne` is function which also cannot be changed.

Comment: @4castle `result` "callback" function `isOne` expects two parameters, one of which is a function. We want to pass the `value` function, with value `x ` passed to callback as parameter to `compare` which will be called within `isOne`  to satisfy function parameter expected. `x` => `isOne(x, compare(value(x)))`  using `.bind()`

Comment: @4castle Attempting to return result of second to last entry at stacksnippet composed as last entry at stacksnippet. Or, determine if it is not possible to use the last pattern to return same result as second to last pattern. The values are not important save for the value passed to innermost  `value` function passed to `compare` function passed to `isOne` function, which is where value is parameter to `value` function.

Comment: @4castle See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36232576/how-to-filter-object-using-array-prototype-filter, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456491/why-is-there-not-a-built-in-method-in-javascript-to-check-if-an-object-is-a-plai/