# Why can't we feed Array.prototype.concat directly into reduce?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript newbie here. Today I learned about `reduce` and set out to implement my own array flatten function.

What I had was

```
var array = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]];
var result = array.reduce(Array.prototype.concat, []); // Causes Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.concat called on null or undefined
var result = array.reduce(Array.prototype.concat.call, []); // Causes Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

While answers in [Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript#) are elegant and idiomatic, I'd really appreciate an illustration on how my attempts failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea with `Array.prototype.concat.call`. With `Array.prototype.concat`, the calls are going to look like this:

```
var concat = Array.prototype.concat;

concat(concat(concat([],
                     [1, 2]),
              [3, 4, 5]),
       [6])
```

which doesn’t work because `Array.prototype.concat` concatenates its arguments to its `this`; calling it as `concat()` gives it a `this` of `undefined`. How about with `call`?

```
var call = Array.prototype.concat.call;

call(call(call([],
               [1, 2]),
          [3, 4, 5]),
     [6])
```

This runs into the same problem, but with `Function.prototype.call` (`Array.prototype.concat` is a function like any other, and inherits its `call` method from `Function.prototype`). `call` tries to call its `this`, but calling it as `call()` gives it a `this` of `undefined`.

You could pass `Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.concat)`… if `reduce` didn’t call its function with more arguments than just the accumulator and the current item. But it does, passing the index of the current item and context array as well, and ruining any chance of making this work by passing only `Array.prototype.concat` wrapped with some builtins.

Comment: _"You could pass `Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.concat)`… if reduce didn’t call its function with more arguments than just the accumulator and the current item."_ Could `.apply()` and `.slice()` be used to use only first two parameters?

Comment: @guest271314: Not easily as far as I know. This quickly gets much longer than `(m, n) => m.concat(n)`.

Comment: Yes, perhaps not easily; though, is it possible? Also, is it possible to call a function reference passed to bind while also passing a parameter to the caller of bound function [How to call function that is parameter to Function.prototype.bind with value passed as parameter to Function.prototype.bind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541169/how-to-call-function-that-is-parameter-to-function-prototype-bind-with-value-pas)?

Comment: @guest271314 @Ryan is there a way in JavaScript to modify the arity of a function without wrapping it in higher order one? I had `var takeTwo = function (func) { return function(...args) { return func(...args.slice(0,2)); }; };` and then `array.reduce(takeTwo(Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.concat)), [])` worked. But defining `takeTwo` defeated the purpose.

Comment: @MengchenYu: There might be a way to do something with another layer of `reduce`, but I’m not really that interested in finding it… there’s nothing special about builtins compared to user-defined functions here.

Answer (score 4):

your code is equivalent of

```
result = array.reduce(fn, []);
function fn(a, b, index, array) { // this is the arguments reduce sends to the callback
    return Array.prototype.concat.call(null, a, b, index, array);
}
```

can you spot the problem?

Comment: Well put. I realised this as soon as I tried my (now deleted) comment above.

Answer (score 0):

This is so because [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) requires a function prototype such that it is an array or list of values to be concatenated to the main array.

However, the callback to [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) requires an `accumulator`, `currentValue`, `currentIndex` and `array` as parameters.

The parameters (as well as what they're supposed to do) don't match and hence, you get unexpected results or errors.