# Simulating a click on a <h:inputFile> is not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.3

I need to upload a file using `<h:inputFile>`. I am using the following code:

```
<h:inputFile id="inputFile" value="#{bean.uploadedFile}" styleClass="hidden">
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.processFile}"/>
</h:inputFile>

...

<button onclick="$('#inputFile').click();">
    Choose file
</button>
```

As you can see, I am hiding the ugly `<h:inputFile>` and just simulating a click on it using a button.

When I click the button, the file explorer is shown and I can choose a file, but, once selected, the page reloads and the `processFile` method is never called.

If I remove the hidden class for the `<h:inputFile>`, click on it and select a file, everything works perfectly.

I tried simulating the click with the `<h:inputFile>` visible, but the same wrong behavior occurs.

Is there anything I can do to simulate the click and retain the `<h:inputFile>` hidden.

I am using Wildfly with JSF 2.3.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based on CSS only and without the need to use Javascript for simulating the click:

```
<label class="input-type-fix">
    <h:inputFile value="#{bean.uploadedFile}">
        <f:ajax listener="#{bean.processFile}"/>
    </h:inputFile>
    <span>Choose file</span>
</label>
```

The CSS:

```
.input-type-fix input[type="file"] {
    position:absolute;
    top: -1000px;
}
```

This way you dont't need to hide the input file and you could add the style you want to the label surrounding the input file. I am using bootstrap, so a posible style could be the following one:

```
<label class="btn btn-primaryinput-type-fix">
    <h:inputFile value="#{bean.uploadedFile}">
        <f:ajax listener="#{bean.processFile}"/>
    </h:inputFile>
    <span>Choose file</span>
</label>
```

As you can see I just add bootstrap classes to the surrounding label.

The question where I found the solution (most of it) is the following one:
[Cross-browser custom styling for file upload button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842274/cross-browser-custom-styling-for-file-upload-button/21842275#21842275)