# Why is it so hard to style the famous Browse button (file input)?

Tags: html, css

Everyone wants (and deserves) to know [**how** to style a file input in an html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226167/how-to-style-input-file-with-css3-javascript) (and there are [several](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) well known [techniques](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/154/howto-style-the-button-of-a-input-typefile-control) for that).  But I'd rather want to know **why** we have to struggle with a technical limitation that seems so trivial and, more than everything.

I'm not really comfortable with [w3c documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html), so maybe I totally missed it during my research, but I can't find any solid documentation about **the origin** of this problem (references would be sweet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This control is rendered by the OS, not HTML. It varies from platform to platform. It's "hard" to style because it's not part of the spec.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, there *is* no "Browse button" in any standard. That's just how your browser happens to render the control. Different browsers render it differently — different colors, different size, different position, etc. It would be nice if there were a way to style inputs more sensibly, but right now their contents are what's known as a "shadow DOM," which basically means "There's stuff inside here, but you can't touch it because it's not supposed to be there in the standard."

Answer (score 2):

It's hard because having a button that you wouldn't recognize as the standard file browsing button could lead to a security risk. That's just like the dialog on onBeforeUnload and other risky feature : they must be recognizable.

Answer (score 2):

Exposure to the file system is very protected. Sometimes access is not even granted (iPhone).