# Can I simulate <input type="file"> using <input type="text">?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write a program using simple html input `type="text"` and a button which will does the functionality of input `type="file"`.

Comment: You can make the file input hidden and make the button trigger the file's onclick. It works, but it is a lot of effort

Comment: My guess is that you want a styled file input. If that's the case, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226167/how-to-style-input-file-with-css3-javascript

Answer (score 1):

HTML From :

```
<input type="file" class="file">
<input type="text" name="file" class="sfile">
<input type="submit" value="send file" name="submit">
```

css :

```
.file{
    visibility:hidden; # don't use display:none; because IE compability in js
}
```

jQuery :

```
$('.sfile').click(function(){
   $('.file').click();
});
$('.file').change(function(){
  $('.sfile').val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

theoretically you could hack it (set 0 opacity to input[file] etc.) but manually typing the path to the text field will not work (will not send a file with the form).
It seems a lot of unnecessary hacking. For what reason?