# How to customize the input type file button and text box

Tags: css, file-upload, customization

I need to customize the file upload button from the below form.

[image: fileupload cusomization]

Now my fileupload button looks like fileupload image.I need to customize it like customize-file upload image

```
<form id="myform" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input id="tele" type="file" name="filename" />
    <br/>
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style "input file" with CSS3 / Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226167/how-to-style-input-file-with-css3-javascript)

Comment: Answer: Style it how you want it to look like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After watching your image, i think u want input type as a textbox and not button.Can u try with keeping input type file as hidden and have textbox like this

```
 <input id="txt" type = "text" value = "Choose File" 
       onclick ="javascript:document.getElementById('file').click();">
      <input id = "file" type="file" style='visibility: hidden;' name="img" onchange="ChangeText(this, 'txt');"/>



function ChangeText(oFileInput, sTargetID) {

    document.getElementById(sTargetID).value = oFileInput.value;
}
```

You can easily apply css to this textbox

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FpBB8/271/)

Comment: Yes its partially working.What i have to do to display the uploaded file name in the text box @ Nitin varpe

Comment: It is not working.can you please update the fiddle with this code@Nitin varpe

Comment: Its working but i am getting the filename along with the path(C:\fakepath\sample.docx) i just want to show the file name@Nitin varpe

Comment: but on my machine its only giving file name. ok u can use substring to get the last string after \, shouldnt be any problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43659/discussion-between-rama-priya-and-nitin-varpe)

Answer (score 1):

Give the styles you want of course, but some examples of how to do this are provided below.

```
input[type="file"] {
       border: 4px solid red;
       border-radius: 40px;
}
```

or try

```
#tele {
     border: 4px solid red;
     border-radius: 50px;
 }
```

if for some reason neither of those works, you might need to be more specific like so

```
#myform #tele {
     border: 3px solid blue;
 }
```

Comment: I need to customize type="file" button  not submit button. @codehorse

Comment: `<input type="file"` is not the "button",..  It is the input text box.

Comment: Your code is not supporting for my requirement.I need to customize the choose file or browse button.can u update in fiddle

Comment: I have updated my post with the image according to my requirement.i hope now you can able to understand my question.@codehorse

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background: url('image_url');` to add a button image

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you could enclose the `input` tag inside a `label` and style the label which would thus overlay the button.