# how to translate Browse or Choose File for form input type=file based on browser language change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

HTML form input type = file is providing "**Browse**"  and "**No file Selected**" in **firefox** and "**choose File**" and "**No File Chosen**" in **chrome** to choose a file.

I have a use case to translate "**Browse**" and "**Choose File**" as per browser language.

is it possible to do without adding any javascript library?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The browser UI language already determines the labels for those form controls. So … do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native input elements are depending on the operating system and the browser that the clients are using. You can workaround with a custom file picker (an input file hidden, a layer that triggers the hidden input file, the text that you like).

You can use this refferences:

[How to style "input file" with CSS3 / Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226167/how-to-style-input-file-with-css3-javascript)

http://markusslima.github.io/jquery-filestyle/

http://moro.es/projects/jquery-nicefileinput-js/

Good luck!