# File upload form style for all browsers

Tags: html, css, jsf-2.2

File upload form style for all browsers

[image]

I use this JSF code for the form

```
<h:inputFile id="fileToUpload" value="#{contacts.file}"/>
    <h:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{contacts.upload()}">
        <f:ajax execute="fileToUpload" />
    </h:commandButton>
```

How I can make the form to look like in one style for all browser?

Comment: duplicate of a duplicate... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226167/how-to-style-input-file-with-css3-javascript or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button

Answer (score 0):

How the upload looks is dependant on how the browser has been designed to render it.

If you want to have the same look and feel across all browsers, then you would need to write a custom control, using a textbox and a button.

Alternatively, you could look at a third party component that does this for you.

Comment: The button itself is, but there are 'workarounds'

Comment: If you find it's not already answered, consider moving your answer into the duplicate question.